# TextBox Binding из отдельного класса

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, textbox

Есть WPF проект с одним MainWindow. Два текстбокса и кнопка. В один текстбокс вводим число, жмём кнопку, происходит действие и результат выводится в соседний текстбокс.

Биндинг работает замечательно пока все эти переменные и т.д. лежат в самом MainWindow. Как только же я выношу их в отдельный класс - биндинг с ними не работает, ничего не определяется. Попытался банальные вещи прописать в path (типа rest.Hop например), но само собой это не сработало.

Есть ли способ решить данную проблему?

С#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    Res rest = new Res();
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        rest.Pop = rest.Hop * 2;
    }
}

public class Res : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _hop;
    public int Hop
    {
        get { return _hop; }
        set
        {
            if (_hop != value)
            {
                _hop = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private int _pop;
    public int Pop
    {
        get { return _pop; }
        set
        {
            if (_pop != value)
            {
                _pop = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="testik1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testik1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Hop, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="177,118,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Pop, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="382,118,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="340,191,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сейчас `DataContext`'ом ваше окна является само окно. Привязка "ищет" свойства `Pop` и `Hop` в `MainWindow`. Но теперь эти свойства находятся в другом классе.

Соответственно нужно `DataContext`'ом вашего окна сделать объект класса `Res`. Т.е.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Res rest;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        rest = new Res();
        DataContext = rest;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        rest?.Pop = rest.Hop * 2;
    }
}
```

Я всего лишь поправил код, чтобы он работал. Но вообще вам стоит посмотреть в сторону паттерна MVVM. Можно начать отсюда: https://habr.com/ru/post/338518/

Comment: Или `Res rest = new Res();` превратить в публичное свойство (`public Res Rest {get;} = new Res();`), тогда привязка будет не `Path=Hop`, а `Path=Res.Hop`. Ну а вообще, это лучше вынести в отдельный класс, ибо таких `Res` может быть много)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ обеими руками за)

Comment: @alladuh Сделал как вы. В итоге ругается на приватный rest как на недопустимый. И далее все rest'ы не существуют в текущем контексте.
Также попробовал способ EvgeniyZ. Но увы всё также - textbox продолжает быть пустым.

Comment: @alladuh всё куда проще - в private rest; нужно было вставить тип Res. В итоге всё заработало.

Comment: @Domed да, виноват, упустил тип